# Angular - canvas.toBlob callback´s argument is null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, blob

Basing my code in these two tutorials I found:

- [Capturing Camera using Angular 5](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/capturing-camera-using-angular-5-2e177c68201f).
- [JavaScript: How to capture image from video?](https://medium.com/@immanubhardwaj/javascript-how-to-capture-image-from-video-ac7dba01a8e7).

I´m trying to get the video´s frames and then convert them into blobs. But I haven´t been able to do it. This is the code I have made for the moment:

#### app.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <button (click)="start()" class="btn btn-primary">Play</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3>
          <video #videoElement></video>
          <canvas #canvasElement style="overflow:auto"></canvas>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('videoElement',  {static: true}) videoElement: any;  
  @ViewChild('canvasElement',  {static: true}) canvasElement: any;  
  video: any;
  canvas: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
    this.canvas = this.canvasElement.nativeElement;
  }

  start() {
    this.initCamera({ video: true, audio: false });
  }

  initCamera(config:any) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(config).then(stream => {
      console.log(stream)
      this.video.srcObject = stream;
      this.video.play();
      this.canvas.width = this.video.videoWidth;
      this.canvas.height = this.video.videoHeight;
      this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight);  
      this.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        const img = new Image();
        console.log(blob);
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

My problem is that the callback´s argument ***blob*** is not having any value (null). So I wonder if anyone could help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the docs of [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) and [`HTMLMediaElement.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) I noticed both of them return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), therefore I used the syntax `async-await` to wait for the methods to finish and set the video, so I could catch the frames eventually and convert them into blobs.

Only change the method `initCamera` in the previous code I posted in the question:

```js
async initCamera(config:any) {
     this.video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(config);
     await this.video.play();
     this.canvas.width = this.video.videoWidth;
     this.canvas.height = this.video.videoHeight;
     this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight);
     this.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        const img = new Image();
        console.log(blob);
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      });
}
```